# Does order of memory allocation matter in PyCUDA's curandom?

Tags: python, cuda, jupyter-notebook, pycuda, curand

I use PyCUDA's interface [[1](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/unified-memory-cuda-beginners/)] over CUDA Unified Memory [[2](https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/driver.html#managed-memory)]. At some point I added random number generators [[3](https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/array.html#module-pycuda.curandom)] and stared to see dead kernels in Jupyter Notebook:
[image: The kernel appears to have died]

I narrowed the problem down to the creation of random number generator. Or, to be precise, to the moment when I do this:

```
import pycuda.curandom
from pycuda import autoinit, driver
import numpy as np

gpu_data_1 = driver.managed_zeros(shape=5, dtype=np.int32, mem_flags=driver.mem_attach_flags.GLOBAL)
gpu_generator = pycuda.curandom.XORWOWRandomNumberGenerator(pycuda.curandom.seed_getter_uniform)
gpu_data_2 = driver.managed_zeros(shape=5, dtype=np.int32, mem_flags=driver.mem_attach_flags.GLOBAL)
```

The code above fails without any error message, but if I put the `gpu_generator = ...` line **one line higher or lower, it appears to work fine**.

I believe PyCUDA might somehow fail to execute the [`prepare` call](https://github.com/inducer/pycuda/blob/17961bec8fdb6d0ec3a809bb7be1a51e4796020a/pycuda/curandom.py#L635), which comes down to this kernel:

```
extern "C" {
    __global__ void prepare(curandStateXORWOW *s, const int n,
        unsigned int *v, const unsigned int o)
    {
      const int id = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
      if (id < n)
        curand_init(v[id], id, o, &s[id]);
    }
}
```

Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: What sort of GPU are you using?

Comment: @talonmies it is a GeForce GTX 1060 3GB

Comment: On a pre-pascal GPU I can understand why this fails, but with a GTX1060 that shouldn't be the case. I have a work around, whether it works for you IDK.

Comment: If you happen to be on windows, the UM will be in a pre-pascal regime, even though you are on a pascal GPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [illegal](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-gpu-exclusive) in a pre-Pascal UM (Unified Memory) regime for host code to touch a managed allocation after a kernel has been launched, but before a `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` has been issued.

I am guessing this code violates this rule. If I run your repro case on a Maxwell system I get this:

```
$ cuda-memcheck python ./idontthinkso.py
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= Error: process didn't terminate successfully
========= Fatal UVM CPU fault due to invalid operation
=========     during write access to address 0x703bc1000
=========
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 1 error
```

That is the managed memory system blowing up. Placing a synchronization call between the random generator setup (which runs a kernel) and the zeros call (which touches managed memory) gets rid of it on my system:

```
$ cat idontthinkso.py 
import pycuda.curandom
from pycuda import autoinit, driver
import numpy as np

gpu_data_1 = driver.managed_zeros(shape=5, dtype=np.int32, mem_flags=driver.mem_attach_flags.GLOBAL)
gpu_generator = pycuda.curandom.XORWOWRandomNumberGenerator(pycuda.curandom.seed_getter_uniform)
autoinit.context.synchronize()
gpu_data_2 = driver.managed_zeros(shape=5, dtype=np.int32, mem_flags=driver.mem_attach_flags.GLOBAL)

$ cuda-memcheck python ./idontthinkso.py
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
```

The UM regime you are in will vary depending on what GPU, driver and OS you use.

Comment: It does solve the problem at hand, I did not know my UM could be in a pre-Pascal regime. It does not solve the problem in my original code since I already had synchronization calls there - I will try to fiddle with it a bit more and assemble a better MCVE if I don't come up with a solution.